# select relations from MANY to MANY in yii framework using Criteria

Tags: php, yii

I have a table `Policy` which links to another table `Currency` and the relation is as below:

```
'policyCurrency' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Currency', 'policy_currencies(PolicyId, CurrencyId)’),
```

I am also using the `search` function provided in the model to get the data and I want to select the `Currency` which resides in the related `Currency` Table as part of the search. Below is my search function.

```
public function search(){

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('PolicyId', $this->PolicyId); 
    $criteria->compare('Name', $this->Name, true);
    $criteria->compare('Amount', $this->Amount, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array( 'criteria' => $criteria));
}
```

When using the search getData:

```
$result = Policy->search()->getData();
```

The result returned is in the format of:

```
PolicyId = 1
Name = 'Test'
Amount = '20'
etc etc etc
```

I want the data related to the relations which is currency in this case be returned as part of the select like this (appending one after the other separated by a ',' since this is a MANY to MANY relation):

```
CurrencyId = 1,2,3
```

**What I have tried:**

Trying to use the

```
$criteria->with = array('policyCurrency');
$criteria->together = true;
```

but i am confused about how to use select to select all records from the first table Policy in my case and all related CurrencyIds seperated by a ',' from the related model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the relation name to the **with** attribute so it does a `JOIN` with Currency and gets all its related data:

```
public function search(){

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = array('policyCurrency');
```

For more info, [check CDBCriteria documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#with-detail).